# Parsing cookie with Omniauth-facebook client side flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, omniauth

I have a legacy app which I've been working to convert to Omniauth since the app currently connects to multiple 3rd party platforms like Twitter and Facebook.  Integrating Omniauth for Facebook on the client side is proving much more time consuming then building it from scratch.  Want to give it one last go, hopefully with insights from the community here.

I've followed the example in omniauth-facebook in the /example Sinatra app for client-side flow, but I keep getting the following error in my logs:

```
Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Dec 31 07:52:01 -0500 2011 
Started GET "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Dec31 07:52:04 -0500 2011

Processing by FacebookUsersController#failure as    Parameters {"message"=>"invalid_credentials"}
```

I was able to get this to work using the server side flow in another branch, having trouble with the client side flow.  Here are the relevant files.  What's going on?

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'xxx', 'xxx', :scope => 'email', :display => 'popup'
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'facebook_users#login_or_register_fb_user'
  match '/auth/failure' => 'facebook_users#failure'
```

**app/views/layouts/application.haml**
This is actually included in the layout through a partial which is the last thing to load on the page.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxx', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));

   $(function() {
     $('.facebook_button').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       FB.login(function(response) {
         if (response.authResponse) { 
           $.get('/auth/facebook/callback');
         }
       }, { scope: 'email'});


     });
   });
</script>
```

**app/controllers/facebook_users_controller.rb**

```
class FacebookUsersController < ApplicationController

  def login_or_register_fb_user
    respond_to do |f|
        f.js {
          MultiJson.encode(request.env)
        }
    end
  end 
  def failure
    respond_to do |f|
         f.js {
           MultiJson.encode(request.env)
         }
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas why I am seeing "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials" in my logs when I try and log a facebook user in?  Is there anything I need in my application controller - a before filter to parse the Facebook cookie or something?  I'm at a loss here.  I'm pretty sure my settings are correct otherwise.

Facebook settings for this app:

- site URL: http://twye.local/
- site domain: twye.local

Thanks for the hand.